# css overflow / inline elements

Tags: css

When you put an inline list of items in a div with a fixed width and set overflow to hidden, the elements stack vertically.

Anyone have any css hacks to get them to remain inline while hidden. Possibly using overflow:hidden without a width?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods that can be used to making a horizontal list. The main ingredient is "display: inline", applied to the "LI" element.

Read this article for details:

http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/horizontal_master.htm

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Have to put elements in a container with a null "big" width so it won't wrap. =P